# Handle colors theme change using state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, user-interface, electron

I have an a desktop app that uses Electron and React.

I want the app to respond to changes in the Windows theme (Dark or Light mode).

I've looked at other implementations online, and I came up to this solution:

Main React component:

```js
const App: React.FC = function () {
    const getTheme = (): Theme => (ipcRenderer.invoke('should-use-dark-colors') ? customDarkTheme : customLightTheme)

    const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(getTheme)

    React.useEffect(function () {
        ipcRenderer.onNativeThemeChanged(() => {
            setTheme(getTheme())
        })
    })

    return (
        <FluentProvider theme={theme}>
            ...
        </FluentProvider>
    )
}
```

preload.js

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
    invoke: (channel) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel),
    onNativeThemeChanged: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on("native-theme-changed", callback)
});
```

And inside the Electron client:

```js
ipcMain.handle('should-use-dark-colors', function (event, ...args) {
    tray.setImage(getIcon())
    return nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors
})

nativeTheme.addListener("updated", function () {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('native-theme-changed')
})
```

I've debugged both IPC routines, they work as expected.

When I open the app it initially uses the correct theme, but if I change my system theme during runtime it doesn't change accordingly.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

Initially I tried to do [this](https://github.com/oliverschwendener/electron-fluent-ui/blob/abce9c70cc402ea44eedf2a2b6f41813e35f659c/src/App.tsx#L10) but couldn't get it to work, so I ended up using a custom hook on the `prefers-color-scheme` CSS feature to detect system theme changes.

This is the result:

```js
const useThemeChange = () => {
    const mediaQuery = () => window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')

    const [isDarkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(mediaQuery().matches)

    useEffect(() => {
        const mediaQueryResult = mediaQuery()
        mediaQueryResult.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
            setDarkTheme(event.matches)
        })
    }, [])

    return isDarkTheme
}

export const App: React.FC = () => {

   const isDarkTheme = useThemeChange()
    return (
        <FluentProvider theme={isDarkTheme ? customDarkTheme : customLightTheme}>
            ...
        </FluentProvider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, it may be better to use theme as a context, rather than as a state. State always need to be passed on explicitly whereas context remains available much like a global to all the children from a top level component where it needs to be defined. From the React official docs (old but relevant : https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for
> a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user,
> theme, or preferred language.

Also see https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext